# Javascript function not found when running UI tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

I'm using Selenium with Visual Studio 2017 on an ASP.NET MVC application. Driver is ChromeDriver 2.42.01. Everything works, however one of my tests involves clicking a div which is wrapped into an anchor:

```
<a class="allowed" href="javascript:loadRegistrationPopUp(10031)">
  <div class="selectContentContainer class-time">
    ...
  </div>
</a>
```

The function is causing an error because it is undefined. 
Looking at the page source in Chrome, I find that a major part of the Javascript is missing, particularly the line that includes my script bundle where the function is living. If I open the very same page in a regular Chrome instance, I can see:

`<script src="/bundles/default?v=3n...pSQ1"></script>`

But that script include (together with the Javascript) is missing when running with Selenium.

To make things even stranger: running the same test on another machine does work, the bundle is there. Same version of Chrome.

What could be causing this?

Comment: You mean that part of HTML is missing when you open the page with Selenium?

Comment: Yes. Updated my question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue and it has absolutely nothing to do with Selenium. There was a check in the code that would exclude the script in case consent is needed (GDPR compliance). The machine where the tests work are using a US based IP address and thus no consent is required. The other machine, where it is failing, had a German IP...